# Piano song when Golgius tries to takes Meliodas' sword in episode 5

Tags: music, seven-deadly-sins

In *Nanatsu no Taizai*, there's an ominous piano soundtrack that plays in season 1 episode 5 when Golgius tries to takes Meliodas's sword. It plays again in season 1 episode 15 when Guila kills the kids bullying zeal. And in Season 2 it plays in episode 5 when Galan pulverizes Meliodas's.

What is the name of this song?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the entire OST and couldn't find the song played there.
I think that track might be too simple and short to be included in the OST.

1 hour soundtrack:
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q5COE6dGUE) 
Playlist of the soundtrack 
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLG-rC_o-lzyAVe_oLtLyrzr6eTfenMipS)

But maybe I missed something.